# Solution of differential equations with discontinuity

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Suppose that we have scalar differential equation

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t)=u(t)
\end{equation}

Here $u(t)$ is a piecewise constant function with discontinuity. If the points of discontinuity is infinitely many, how would it affect the solution of the ordinary differential equation above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions for the solution of the problem:

> $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = F(t,x(t)), \quad x(t_0)=x_0 ,$$

to exist and to be unique is that $F \in \mathcal{C}^0_{t,x}$ and Lipschitz continuous for $t> t_0$. Then, the solution of the problem is given by:

> $$\color{blue}{x(t) =x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} F(t,x(t))\, \mathrm{d} t}$$

Note that for the function $F$ to be integrable in $t> t_0$, it must contain finitely many discontinuities so $x(t)$ remains continuous in $t>t_0$ whilst, otherwise, $x'(t)$ may not, in general.

As an example, consider the problem:

> $$ x'(t) = H(t-1), \quad x(0)=0, \quad t > 0.  $$

Its solution is then given by:

> $$\boxed{x(t) = (t-1) H(t-1)} $$

which is continuous but not differentiable at $t=1$.

Cheers!

Comment: You seem knowledgeable about this subject. It seems that $H(t-1)$ is not Lipschitz any interval containing $t=1$. I am curious that if $F$ is only piecewise continuous (with finitely many discontinuities), can we guarantee the existence of continuous solution $x$?